# How to work with two or more tables (sqlite-net-plc)

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

Created two tables

```
public TodoItemDatabase(string dbPath)
{
    database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    database.CreateTableAsync<OneTable>().Wait();
    database.CreateTableAsync<OtherTable>().Wait();
   }
```

Created save methods in one file

Only one method works.

```
public Task<int> SaveItemAsync(ModelOneTable item)
{
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
    return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else {
    return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
}
public Task<int> SaveItemAsyncOther(OtherTable item)
{
  if (item.ID != 0)
  {
    return database.UpdateAsync(item);
  }
  else {
    return database.InsertAsync(item);
  }
}
```

Two methods should work. 
doing like here https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/databases/

Answer (score 0):

Edit your method like so:

```cs
public TodoItemDatabase(string dbPath)
{
    CreateDb(dbPath);
}
```

```cs
public async void CreateDb(string dbPath)
{
    database = new SQLiteAsyncConnection(dbPath);
    // wait until first query completed
    await database.CreateTableAsync<OneTable>();
    // then execute second create query
    await database.CreateTableAsync<OtherTable>();
}
```

Comment: 1/ could not find type or namespace async
2/ await can only be used in methods with the async modifier

Comment: 3/ ```await``` same ```await();``` ?

Comment: Oops, sorry, didn’t mention this was constructor. Please see my edited answer.